# bash: command not found capify . RVM, Mac 10.8.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, path, rubygems, capistrano

I'm having troubles getting the capistrano `capify .` command to work. I have installed the gem (tried manually and via the gemfile to see if it would help) successfully as it appears and I am using RVM and mac osx 10.8.4.

All of the documented issues with this issue point seem to a path issue, as my `etc/paths` file seems very different to the results of `echo $PATH` this would seem accurate. However, I'm not sure what to rectify and what to add to get things working.

How can I change my settings and get the capify . command to work?

Below is my env info. If anyone needs more code just shout.

sudo nano etc/paths

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
```

result of `echo $PATH`

```
/Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin:/Users/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/Users/andrew/.rvm/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/andrew/.rvm/bin:/home/user/.gem/ruby/1.8
```

bundle install

```
Using capistrano (3.0.0)
```

bundle show capistrano

```
/Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/capistrano-3.0.0
```

running with bundle exec

```
bundle exec capify .
bundler: command not found: capify
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

Comment: The output of `which capify` is not found also or only within the bundled environment?

Comment: Hi trh - which capify returns nothing in any environment

Comment: And if you instead run `bundle exec cap install` is your Capfile and deploy directory generated?

Comment: Ah yes that command worked in creating the following - mkdir -p config/deploy
create config/deploy.rb
create config/deploy/staging.rb
create config/deploy/production.rb
mkdir -p lib/capistrano/tasks
Capified. Put this in an answer and ill gladly accept.

Comment: added answer to reflect link with issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems it's deprecated.  Lucky you found this, I need this tomorrow :)

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/679

Instead of

```
capify .
```

run

```
cap install
```

These can be encapsulated with bundle exec as well.